# API keys with referer restrictions cannot be used with this API

Tags: google-maps

When i access the API getting below error response

```
{
"error_message" : "API keys with referer restrictions cannot be used with this API.",
"results" : [],
"status" : "REQUEST_DENIED" 
}
```

I have verified all the setting based on google documentation.

Google console settings:

[image]

Captured from chrome Network tab:

[image]

Any help you can give will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to use IP restrictions on keys used on web services.

Comment: @geocodezip I am calling from web page how can i give IP's

Comment: If you are using it in the client (a browser/web page), use the equivalent Google. Maps Javascript API v3 service with the HTTP referrer set to your website.

Comment: @geocodezip Maps Javascript API seems like it should work but failed in my test so the answer below specifying the specific API seems to solve the problem.

Comment: This is still a problem 2 years later. Having the same issue!!!

Answer (score 3):

Select a specific API Restriction to solve this problem. Using "Maps Javascript API" failed for my Geocoding requirement but the "Geocoding API" worked perfectly to remove the error you are noting.

[image: API Selection]

Comment: I wonder if it's sufficient to restrict only by API?

Answer (score 2):

Try using your server **IP Address** as **Application restrictions**. Should work then.

[image]

Comment: Setting a server IP address restriction will not work if you use the AP from a web browser.

Comment: I don't get why everyone is saying use IP address instead. It might work, but those of us using it in a browser cannot restrict to a specific IP or range of IP.