# Using places API from Firebase Cloud Functions with restricted API Key

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-places-api

I recently restricted an api key to accept requests from specific websites, but I use the same api key from Firebase Cloud Functions for Places search.

What url do I add for the cloud functions request?

Url is built like this

```
const urlFindPlaceFromText = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext";
const fields = "formatted_address,name,geometry,icon,rating,price_level,place_id";
const location = "point:$latitude, $longitude";
const url = `${urlFindPlaceFromText}/json?input=${searchString}&inputtype=textquery&language=en&fields=${fields}&locationbias=${location}&key=${apiKey}`;
const placesRequest = await axios.get(url)
```

Response:

```
data: {
>      candidates: [],
>      error_message: 'API keys with referer restrictions cannot be used with this API.',
>      status: 'REQUEST_DENIED'
>    }
```

[image]

Comment: A separate key should work for server side apps. Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167695/api-key-browser-api-keys-cannot-have-referer-restrictions-when-used-with-this-ap)?

Comment: HTTP referrer is the domain name of the website. Where is the API Key used (browser or backend server)? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer

Comment: Please check my recommendations below and let me know if those were helpful

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing looks like you are making the API call server side. Because you have placed a referrer restriction on your [API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/get-api-key#add_key), it will be limited to executing on the browser with the web service APIs.
As mentioned in the comments above,you may create a separate key to use server-side. You can change your restriction from a browser restriction to a server restriction by using IP addresses to restrict access, instead of browser referrers.
[Check this APIs FAQ on switching key type to a server restricted key](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#switch-key-type)

Also check these similar example for more information:

- [Key restrictions by IP address not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48134596/google-maps-key-restrictions-by-ip-address-not-working)
- [How to get IP address from client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68964821/firebase-functions-how-to-get-ip-address-from-client)
- [Cloud function secure HTTPS endpoint with API key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52908611/firebase-cloud-functions-secure-https-endpoints-with-api-key)
- [API keys referrer restrictions cannot be used with this API
  error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52199784/api-keys-with-referer-restrictions-cannot-be-used-with-this-api)